# PWA: Como salvar um POST offline e dispará-lo quando a aplicação estiver online?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, pwa, service-worker

Pelo que vi é possível salvar requisições GET em cache / service workers para que elas sejam disparadas quando a aplicação voltar online. É possível fazer a mesma funcionalidade com um **POST**?

Isso é recomendado? Ou existe alguma alternativa para salvar requests quando um PWA fica offline?

Comment: Uma alternativa para guardar os dados e fazer o post quando a aplicação estiver online seria guardar os dados num banco de dados não relacional. Uma alternativa seria o IndexDB. Aqui você tem um tutorial sobre ele: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/IndexedDB/Usando_IndexedDB

Answer (score -3):

Depende muito da sua necessidade especifica, mas você pode salvar a informação como um rascunho e permitir que o próprio usuário envie ela se for o caso de simplificação do fluxo.

Mas segue um exemplo de implementação para lidar com o armazenamento de requisições no cache.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Verificar se é uma requisição POST
  if (event.request.method === 'POST') {
    event.respondWith(handlePostRequest(event.request));
  }
});

function handlePostRequest(request) {
  // Criar uma chave única para identificar a requisição
  const requestId = generateRequestId(request);

  // Armazenar a requisição no cache local
  return caches.open('post-requests-cache')
    .then(cache => {
      return cache.match(requestId)
        .then(cachedResponse => {
          if (cachedResponse) {
            // Se a resposta estiver em cache, retorná-la
            return cachedResponse;
          } else {
            // Se a resposta não estiver em cache, enviar a requisição ao servidor
            return fetch(request)
              .then(response => {
                // Clonar a resposta para que possa ser armazenada no cache
                const responseClone = response.clone();
                
                // Armazenar a resposta no cache local
                cache.put(requestId, responseClone);
                
                return response;
              })
              .catch(error => {
                // Lidar com erros de conexão ou falha na requisição
                console.error('Erro na requisição POST:', error);
                // Retornar uma resposta de erro personalizada, se necessário
              });
          }
        });
    });
}

function generateRequestId(request) {
  // Gerar uma chave única para identificar a requisição POST
  // Pode ser um hash do corpo da requisição ou algum identificador único
  // Aqui, estou usando o URL da requisição como chave
  return request.url;
}
```

Também pode dar uma olhada no seguinte link:
https://medium.com/@adamrackis/making-your-web-app-work-offline-with-service-workers-and-indexeddb-6ce9c538c48